# Specify reason to use rtrim function

Tags: php

I have tried using

```
$file = "finisv.php";
$folder = rtrim($file, ".php");
echo $folder; // finisv
```

It gives me proper result like `finisv`.But when I tried to use below code

```
$file = "finish.php";
$folder = rtrim($file, ".php");
echo $folder; // finis
```

It gives me wrong output like `finis` but I need to get output like `finish`.What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Duplicate to the point where it feels like trolling

Comment: I want correct reason

Comment: Then [read the friendly manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) that explains how `rtrim()` works and what it actually does, especially the bit about the `character_mask` parameter (`Simply list all __characters__ that you want to be stripped.`); and read the answers/comments against the identical question from just a few hours ago that I flagged as a duplicate

Comment: my main point is why rtrim() escapes all characters from string

Comment: BECAUSE THAT IS WHAT `rtrim()` DOES..... that second argument is a list of characters to remove, not a "string"...... RTFM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use trim.

It removes all trailing letters in ".php" individually so it removes the h to.
Even if you make your `$file`string "dhhhphphphphhphpp......php" the result wil be `d`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

use

```
substr($file, 0, -4);
```

or use

```
$file = preg_replace("/.php$/", "", $file);
```

edit: typo :|